# How to stop parsing XML after a certain number of items have been read?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I'm parsing very large XML and using this as a guide: http://www.php.net/manual/en/example.xml-structure.php. I implemented a counter that increases each time an element is read and want to stop parsing after reading the first 10 elements.

Here's the code I tried:

```
function startElement($parser, $name, $attrs) {
    if ($count == 10) {
        print_r($items);
        break; //this is not working, is exiting the script.
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Yes, I used a return false;

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

Since `startElement` is assigned as the `start_element_handler` of the `$xml_parser`, the `startElement` handler keeps getting indirectly called in the `while` loop:

```
xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement");
// code excluded for brevity
while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
    if (!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
        // code excluded for brevity
    }
}
```

---

### Solution

If the XML is very large and you don't want to spend cycles parsing the entire thing because you're only interested in elements at the beginning, you can use your `$count` to `break` out of the `while` loop:

```
while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
    if($count > 10) break;
    if(!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
        // code excluded for brevity
    }
}
```

---

### Additional Information

Because you're reading in 4096 bytes at a time, you'll probably end up with more than 10 items in your `$items` array. You can decrease that number to, say, 2048 or 1024 bytes depending on your input.

#### Variable scope

If you're using variables defined and used a scope outside of a function that aren't passed to it, you have to use the `global` keyword before using those variables. For example, if you defined `$count = 0` near the beginning of your program and want to increment it in your `endElement` handler, it should look something like this:

```
function endElement($parser, $name)  {
    global $count;
    $count++;
}
```

#### `array_slice`

You can get rid of all but the first 10 elements of your `$items` array like this:

```
$output = array_slice($items, 0, 10);
```